# Do not change the router values ​in the address

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I have a page (index) with an **@ActionLink** that opens another page to edit an invoice, the page will appear correctly, but the [Url-address] shows the number for the invoice, and when I change the number for the invoice in the [**Url-address**], it means that he opened another invoice, and I want the modification page not to open from By modifying the [**Url-address**] or using a direct link, I found a nice way, but it is used with [**Post**] and not Get. Is there a way to protect the [**Url-address**] of the page from being modified and its values?

***View Index:***

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText: "Edit_Invoice",
    actionName: "Invoice_Edit",
    controllerName: "Invoice",
    routeValues: new { ID_Invoice = 2 },
    htmlAttributes: new { area = "Pro"})
```

***Controller :***

```
[HttpGet]

public ActionResult Invoice_Edit(int id_invoice)
{
    Table.Invoice invoice = (from i in Cn.Invoice 
                             where i.ID_Invoice == id_invoice 
                             select i).FirstOrDefault();
  
        return View(invoice;
}
```

***View Invoice_Edit:***

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID_Invoice)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date_Invoice)

<button>save</button>
```

When you open the invoice modification page, its number will appear in the address as in the link below

> https://localhost:44320/Pro/Invoice/Invoice_Edit?ID_Invoice=2

**I only want to open invoices that are selected from the page only.**

**Update 1** : Change  Title Answer

Answer (score 0):

if you what users to open only invoices that they are allowed to open, antiforgery token has nothing to do with it. You neeed server side validation, authentication and authorization. All of these should be implemented on the server side. Client side javascript code is not enough.

Anti-Forgery Tokens don't make a lot of sense for any request where you're not modifying and persisting data.  So I recommend to remove [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from your GET since GET request will be returned to the user, not the attacker.

AntiForgeryToken is designed for POST requests and it expects the token in Request.Form collection. You can just use post instead of get to receive data. Or you can use ajax. Google and you will find some examples.

But make sure that you are using them when you're creating, updating or deleting data.

Comment: Nice talk, but how do I make the user not open the link directly without entering the page, meaning not to modify the (id) number from the address.

Comment: Antiforgery token works only from the user computer. If user fakes id antiforgery token will be send in any case.  You have to check on the  server side if this user is allowed to get invoice#2. It is about user authentication. User can change invoice id manually any time, but antiforgery token will be ok.

Comment: @ebrahemalabdaly Check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks to understand how it works